# using https instead http prevents CSRF

Tags: csrf

If we use https instead http, it should prevent CSRF attacks - right? Google only says how to prevent CSRF on application level(( But no articles for https connections(

Comment: Totally unrelated. Try reading about [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

Comment: Why not? HTTPs encrypts content. If attacker can not encrypt content - how it can laumch CSRF?

Comment: Did you look at the link?

Comment: Sure. How have red what CSRF is but no word to HTTPS.

Comment: Because (as I wrote before..) is totally unrelated. HTTPS doesn't help prevent CSRF, it's not designed to do so